# IBM Urbancode AddVersionStatus API call from Powershell How?

Tags: rest, powershell, urbancode

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_6.2.7/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/udclient_addversionstatus.html

How to make this PUT call using Powershell please?. I am using Powershell 5.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post while trying to do the same thing. The problem for me was in knowing what **exactly** the correct URL was (see Adam Parsons' answer):

```
$URL = "url-goes-here"
```

After **a lot** of searching (IBM's documentation was not worth much in this effort), I was able to identify the correct URL by way of watching traffic in Chrome developer tools (thanks to Darrell Schrag's blog post: https://drschrag.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/the-udeploy-rest-api).

For those searching for this, my PowerShell REST call sequence now looks like this (and executes successfully):

```
$tokenEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes( "PasswordIsAuthToken:{"token":"$authToken"}" ))
$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic "+$tokenEncoded}

# 1. Get component version ID
$uri = "$uDeployServer:8443/cli/version/getVersionId`?component=$componentName&version=$versionName"
$versionId=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $headers

# 2. Add component version status
$uri = "$uDeployServer:8443/rest/deploy/version/$versionId/status/$versionStatus"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method PUT -Headers $headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this...

```
$Hash = @{
        Component="StringValue"
        Version="StringValue"
        Status="StringValue"
        }


$Json = $Hash | ConvertTo-Json
$URL = "url-goes-here"
$Cred = Get-Credential

Invoke-RestMethod -Method "POST" -Uri $url -Credential $Cred -Body $Json
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6